# In a shell script, how do I replace the first occurrence of a string, after a different string

Tags: bash, sh, dash-shell

I have a simple config file that looks a bit like this:

```
[sectionA]
url = value1
username = value2
password = value3

[sectionC]
url = value1
username = value2
password = value3

[sectionB]
url = value1
username = value2
password = value3
```

And I want to replace the username for SectionB to be `valueX` without touching SectionA's or SectionC's username.

I've tried some variations on `sed`, but as far as I've managed to fathom it seems to operate on individual lines.

How do I do the equivalent of

1. Search for StringA (in this case `[SectionB]`)
2. Find the next occurrence of StringB (`username = value2`)
3. Replace with StringC ('username = valueX`)

Comment: This is possible using the shell, but would be much easier using a language with an ini parsing library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `sed`:

```
sed '/sectionB/,/\[/s/username.*/username = valueX/' input
```

#### `awk`:

```
awk -vRS='' -vFS='\n' -vOFS='\n' '
$1~/sectionB/{
    sub(/=.*$/, "= valueX", $3)
}
{
    printf "%s\n\n", $0
}' input
```

Comment: I had no idea it could be so simple.  Nice +1

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Some of the sed syntax is a little... cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

This multi-line sed should do the trick:

```
sed -E -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/\[sectionB\]([^[]*)username = [a-zA-Z0-9_]+/\[sectionB\]\1username = valueX/g;p;}' input.txt
```